# How can I automatically validate the dependencies in my RCP .product file?

Tags: eclipse, dependencies, rcp

I'm a bit new to building Eclipse RCP applications, and I'm finding it necessary to validate the list of plugins in the **Dependencies** tab of the `.product` file. But Eclipse (Indigo) offers no tools to help. In the launch configurations, there are great tools in the **Plug-ins** tab (buttons **Add Required Plug-ins** and **Validate Plug-ins**). It seems like there are 2 really obvious solutions that just aren't available:

1. Add a new button (or something) to copy the exact list of plugins from a `.launch` into a `.product` file (I tried to manually copy the text of the backing files, but the xml formats differ), or
2. Put the same two buttons in the **Dependencies** tab of the `.product` file.

I'm only creating one simple plugin, and the dependency list has 300 entries... very tedious to manually compare with a `.launch`! Am I missing something, is there actually a way to validate these dependencies directly in the `.product` file? Thanks for your help.

Byron

Answer (score 0):

Here are two posibilities to get what you want:

### Create a new product configuration

1. In the **New Product Configuration** dialog under **Initialize the file content** select **Use a launch configuration** and choose your Plug-In's launch configuration
2. Open the **.product* file, switch to the **Dependencies** tab and you can see all Plug-Ins which are required to run your defining Plug-In

### Edit an existing product configuration

1. Open the **.product* file, switch to the **Overview** tab and select your Plug-In's launch configuration under **Product Definition / Application**
2. Switch to the **Dependencies** tab and add your defining Plug-In via the *Add* button
3. Select the **Include optional dependencies when computing required plug-ins** checkbox (which you can find at the bottom)
4. Hit the **Add Required Plug-Ins** button and you can see all Plug-Ins which are required to run your defining Plug-In